# Automatically update a column with a special date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 2 columns:

1. `ExpireDate`(DateTime)
2. `IsExpired`(Bit).

Is there any way that I can check automatically if `ExpireDate >= Today Date` and change the `IsExpired` column from false to true?

In fact, I would this process happened for each record in `ExpireDate` and I don't want check all of record manually to found what recode is expire then change `IsExpired` column.

Comment: you can write an sql query and execute it!

Comment: Why do you need this? You can bring back an `IsExpired` field in your `SELECT` statements with a non persisted computed column defined as `CASE WHEN ExpireDate <=  GetDate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. (rather than needing to update a redundant column daily). Your `WHERE` clause should still just be on `ExpireDate` though rather than a calculated column for sargability reasons.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the `IsExpired` field with an update query like this:

```
UPDATE table SET IsExpired = 1 WHERE ExpireDate >= GetDate()
```

And if you want it to happen automatically you can schedule a job doing this using the SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
update yourtablename
set isexpired = 1
where ExpireDate >= convert(date,getdate())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want this to happen automatically, then use a view or [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).  You can add a computed column like this:

```
alter table YourTable
   add column isexpired as (case when ExpireDate >= getdate() then 1 else 0 end);
```

(You might have to drop the column first.)

The advantage of a computed column is that it never gets out of date.